# No se como traer info de la API

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Es una api de paises, lo que quiero logarar es extrraer los lenguajes que estan dentro de un abjeto, para obtener los idiomas, pero por alguna razon hay un problema con el tipado cuando quiero utilizar Object.values con la api

mi interface:

```
export interface Country {
  languages: Languages;
}



export interface Languages {
  eng: string;
  hin: string;
  tam: string;
}
```

Lo que trae la api:

```
[
 {
  ...
  languages : {eng: 'English', hin: 'Hindi', tam: 'Tamil'}
  ...
}
]
```

Como lo utilizo:

```
      <h3>Common language: {country[0]?[Object.values(country[0]?.languages).join(', ')</h3>
```

El error:

```
: expected
```

y si coloco eso mismo en on console.log(), dice este error:

```
console.log(Object.values(country[0]?.languages).join(','));
error: type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo que tu pondría ese objeto que tienes en una variable para un uso más fácil.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías usarla con lo que tienes.

```
interface ObjetoConLenguajes {
  languages: {[key: string]: string};
  // aquí, utilizamos un índice de tipo para definir las claves y valores del objeto "languages"
  // el índice de tipo "{[key: string]: string}" significa que las claves serán strings y los valores también serán strings.
}

const objeto: ObjetoConLenguajes[] = [
  {
    ...
    languages : {eng: 'English', hin: 'Hindi', tam: 'Tamil'}
    ...
  }
];

console.log(objeto[0].languages.eng); // "English"
console.log(objeto[0].languages["hin"]); // "Hindi"
console.log(objeto[0].languages["tam"]); // "Tamil"
```

primero definimos una interfaz `ObjetoConLenguajes` que especifica que nuestro objeto tendrá una propiedad `languages`, que a su vez será un objeto con claves y valores de tipo `string`. Luego, asignamos el objeto a una variable llamada objeto.